# MySQL query comment number of articles together with article details

Tags: mysql, join

I have three tables, Users, Articles and Comments, as below:

Users:

```
id | username
```

Articles:

```
id | user_id | title | content | time
```

Comments:

```
id | article_id | content | time
```

`user_id` is the article writer's user id in `Users`; `article_id` is the commenting article's id in `Articles`.

Now I want to list articles, showing their writer's `username`, `title`, `content`, `time`, and `number of comments`. The `username` is from `Users`, `number of comments` should be from `Comments` by counting something, and the rest fields are from `Articles`.

How to write the query in a single statement?

I tried

```
SELECT a.*, count(c.id) AS NUM_COMMENTS, u.username
    FROM Commetns c
    JOIN Users u
    INNER JOIN Articles a
    WHERE a.id = c.article_id AND u.id=a.user_id
    GROUP BY a.id
```

But this only returns articles **with** comments. I want the articles **without** comments also listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `left join` to get the articles without comments

```
select 
a.*,
count(c.id) AS NUM_COMMENTS,
u.username
from Articles a
JOIN Users u on  u.id=a.user_id
left join Commetns c on c.article_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id
```